# How to replace helm values.yaml by using the kustomize configMapGenerator generated name?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I use `kustomize` to generate various `configMap` as the following example: -

```yaml
# kustomization.yaml

configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config-path # <-- My original name.
  files:
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - ...
  - fileN.txt
```

The output is as the following example: -

```yaml
# my-configmap.yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  file1.txt: |
  ...
  file2.txt: |
  ...
  fileN.txt |
  ...
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-path-mk89db6928 # <-- There is a hashed value appended at the end.
```

Oh the other hand, I have a third-party `helm` which requires to override the `values.yaml` as the following: -

```yaml
# third-party-chart-values.yaml

customArguments:
  - --config.dir=/config
...

volumes:
  - mountPath: /config
    name: my-config-path # <--- Here, I would like to replace with `my-config-path-mk89db6928`.
    type: configMap
```

Do we have any way to replace the `my-config-path` at the `third-party-chart-values.yaml` with the generated value  `my-config-path-mk89db6928` from the file named `my-configmap.yaml`? (Note, if the `configMap` is changed the hashed, e.g. `mk89db6928` also be changed, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep the hash? Because you could prevent it with:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

Then you'd have a predictable name. Although that would cause a collision if you installed the same helm chart more than once in the same namespace.